# Extremely customizable screenshot tool for OS X

Tags: gratis, osx, screenshot

I'm on OS X 10.9, and am aware of the awesome native screenshot tool:
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for fullscreen screenshot and
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> for a screenshot of a portion of the screen.

However, I'm looking to "automate" some screenshotting task, and thus need a program/application to:

1. Allow me to designate a portion of the screen I wanted screenshotted *beforehand*
2. Allow me to take a screenshot of that designated area in **as few keystrokes as possible**. 1 keystroke would be nice.

**Does a tool like this exist for OS X?**

Comment: [SnapzPro](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/) does that (shortcut+enter to execute the same operation as last time) but it's a paid app.